# external links without http|https fails

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm not very good at regular expressions at all.

the RewriteRule I use is:

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /kurum.php?sef=$1 [QSA]
```

Which converts

http://fxrehber.com/kurum.php?sef=gcm-forex to
http://fxrehber.com/gcm-forex

my php file handles the URLs as :

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $demoUrl ?>" target="_blank">Open Demo Account</a>
```

If I don't include "http://" in my php file the links goes to

http://fxrehber.com/www.example.com

So I keep the URLs in the database as : www.example.com

But now I need to use URLs with https and I need to remove "http://" from the php file and I might be able to save the URLs in the database as both www.example.com and https://www.example.com

What's the way to do this? Changing my RewriteRule or modifying my php file with some regex?

Comment: I didn't understand your problem completely. Can you try to explain your problem with 1or 2 examples?

Comment: Hi, I have a bunch of URLs saved in my database as "www.example.com" format. Because of the RewriteRule, if I don't include "http://" in my php file the links goes to http://fxrehber.com/www.example.com. But I don't want to add http to every link because I want to be able to save URLs starting with both www and http/https format. So I need a if/else structure using a regex that checks URL. If URL starts with www add http in front of it, ELSE leave it alone (for the URLs starting with http or https). I hope I could explain the problem. Btw adding http/https all the URLs in db is another option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I was so concerned about the regex and RewriteRule so while explaining my problem I understood it can simply be solved by checking if the URL has http/https in it:

```
if (0 !== stripos($demoUrl, 'http://') && 0 !== stripos($demoUrl, 'https://')) 
{ $demoUrl = 'http://' . $demoUrl; }
```

Now I can save all 3 types of URLs (starting with www, http and https)in the database and don't need to modify the old ones.
But  I still wonder if there's a way to use links without http/https by a rewriterule. (as I stated before, when I click a link "www.example.com" in my site, it tries to go www.mysite.com/www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression in `rewrite` rule is for enabling clean URL. The mechanism is passing entire URI to `kurum.php` - via `$_GET['sef']`, where content [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20router) should happen.

The following rules will *disable* `rewrite` if there actually is matching file/directory with the requesting URI.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /kurum.php?sef=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks but when I add them to my htaccess file I still get 404 error. If I keep all the URLs in the database with http or https there won't be problem but I don't want to modify all the URLs. I need something that will accept all kinds of URLs (starting with www or http). I think it can be done with regex with if/else structure ? Like: If it starts with www then add http, else use what you read from database...